# Custom post type active menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type called “team" and added the link to the archive page to the WP menu.
Once user clicks on it, he is shown all team members and that current page is highlighted in the menu.
But when i click on individual team member, his page opens and the “Team” in the menu isn’t highlighted anymore, and it should be.

This is how it shows up when the team page is opened:

```
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item active”>
<a href="http://localhost:8888/site/team/">Team</a>
</li>
```

and this is what i get in the menu when i open individual member page:

```
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom”>
<a href="http://localhost:8888/site/team/">Team</a>
</li>
```

Since I’m not a PHP developer, i don’t have any idea on how to make it work, any suggestion would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got this to work for me, taken and edited from, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50902/highlight-menu-item-when-on-a-custom-post-type). Where I have 'bonsai' change it to your custom post type. Where I have put 'menu-item-299', change it to the id of your menu item that you want to keep highlighted.

```
function change_page_menu_classes($menu)
{
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'bonsai')
    {
        $menu = str_replace( 'current-menu-item', '', $menu ); // remove all current_page_parent classes
        $menu = str_replace( 'menu-item-299', 'menu-item-299 current-menu-item', $menu ); // add the current_page_parent class to the page you want
    }
    return $menu;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'change_page_menu_classes', 10,2 );
```

Let me know if you have issues, cos maybe they affect me to :)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Gavin :)
I did found few snippets but none of them didnt worked in my case, will try it out with this one.

Nope, not a PHP dev, i created the fields using a WP Types plugin following an online tutorial :D

Comment: Ok, after posting my answer I noticed my the 2 sites I added custome menu types to had the same issue. So I sorted it out :). I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Jusy copy and paste the above code in a file 'functions.php' in your theme root folder, then edit as described :)

Comment: Yep, did it, changed the custom post type and the menu ID, but still nothing :( http://i.imgur.com/wGEfEKE.png

Comment: Yep, dunno why it isnt working on my end, i have changed the post type and the menu ID and nothing, it still doesnt get new class

Comment: Hmm, next step. At the beginning of the change_page_menu_classes add `echo "<h1>HERE</h1>";` then click on the menu. You should see if it as least calling the function.

Comment: Yep, it is, i get Here echoed, so it is working.Gonna try playing with classes for a minute

Comment: Good start. Move the h1 line to within the 'if' loop... to check if your post type is found... if so you are almost there.

Comment: Did that too, i get Here echoed 4 times, both at team archive page and on single team page :) So, it must be something with ID's or classes

Comment: Wierd trick to try. Go to setting/permalink in admin. click 'save', then refresh the site/ The permalink tend to get a bit screwy when adding custom posts, so mebbe this is a problem as well. You sure you got the id right (right click on menu item, inspect element... and check it's classes?

Comment: Yep, ID is 17 :( Maybe i am doing something wrong, so here is a screenshot of how it looks on team page when its active and on member page when it is not: http://i.imgur.com/LpER2Sd.jpg

And sorry for boring you this much :(

Comment: Ok, I am guessting the plugin you used, or the theme is messing things around a bit, as I don't see 'menu-item-17' in the class. so change the second line in the if statement to '$menu = str_replace( 'menu-item-type-custom', 'menu-item-17 menu-item-type-custom current-menu-item', $menu );' Me bored.... nah :)

Comment: Yep, i am using a blank theme, so it could be that is missing something out.
About this last snippet, it does works, but it also adds active class to another custom post type that im having xD

Nothing, thank you for all your help, i will try to figure it out :)

Comment: Lol, ok, good luck. At least you know this code snippet is working. It's just a case now of adding the id to the menu class somehow.(would be easy if you knew jQuery).... cheers.

Comment: Yep, will figure it out somehow :) Once again, thanks!

Comment: One last link to maybe help you out... https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-menu-item-not-getting-current-menu-item-class-added

Comment: It is on localhost :( Will tinker around a bit to see what can i find

Comment: Woho :) It works after i played with the menu and changed it from 'walker' => new Bootstrap_walker() to 'walker' => '' (it works fine so i guess this wont be a problem)

I have created another rule for another post type (http://pastebin.com/ytk4S4Ej) is this good way to do it? And one again, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I did as I also have multiple post types. Great stuff. Always pays to persevere.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a very simple filter in functions.php
make sure that you have used the argument `has_archive => true` when registering CPT or using `register_post_type()`

```
//ADDING AN ACTIVE CLASS TO THE CUSTOM POST-TYPE MENU ITEM WHEN VISITING ITS SINGLE POST PAGES
function custom_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){            
        global $post;

        $classes[] = ($menu_item->url == get_post_type_archive_link($post->post_type)) ? 'current-menu-item active' : '';
        return $classes;
    }
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'custom_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```

Hope this will help someone, comment and vote up if it helps you.

Comment: This is an amazing fix! htanks :)

Comment: @Tatof, yes it's amazing :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

More simple way without `get_post_type_archive_link` function:

```
function custom_active_item_classes( $classes = [], $menu_item = false ) {
    global $post;

    $classes[] = ( in_array( 'menu-item-object-' . $post->post_type, $classes ) ) ? 'current-menu-item active' : '';

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'custom_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```